# HTML5 Content Editable DIV focus

Tags: jquery, html

I have a DIV with `<div contentEditable="true" id="content"></div>`, my problem is that after using javascript to post off the div's contents, the cursor is still flashing within the DIV and I wanted this div to lose focus after submitting its contents, that is how can I get the cursor to be removed from the DIV after submitting? I have already tried setting the blur to this DIV after submitting but to no avail.

```
    $('.save-button').on('click',function(){
    var newBio = $("#content").text();
    newBio = $.trim(newBio);

    $.post(postdatahere,
            function(data) {
            $("#content").blur();
            $('.save-button').hide();
        });
});
```

Also, is it better to use `.text()` to get data from editable DIV or `.html()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, you need to focus a different user text input to move the cursor, since the cursor stays there after the content editable div is blurred.

So your code would look something like this:

```
    $('.save-button').on('click',function(){
    var newBio = $("#content").text();
    newBio = $.trim(newBio);

    $.post(postdatahere,
            function(data) {
            $("#SomeUserInput").focus();
            $(".save-button").focus();
            $('.save-button').hide();
        });
});
```

Though shouldn't `.save-button` be an id instead of a class? 
If so it would be

```
    $.post(postdatahere,
            function(data) {
            $("#SomeUserInput").focus(); //blur #content by focusing on different element
            $('#save-button').focus(); // focus on the button to remove focus from #SomeUserInput and because it is going to be hidden anyways.
            $('#save-button').hide();
        });
});
```

( And Yes, this is somewhat of a hack.)

When it comes to whether to use `.text()` or `.html()`, it depends on what you want. If you want styling (Italics, bold font, etc.) you will want to use `.html()`, but if you do that make sure you have a server side filter of some sort so you do not get any bad scripts on you website. Otherwise, `.text()` will do just fine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was thinking of putting focus on the 'body' but that didn't work, save-button is a Button element, can it still get focus like a DIV?

Comment: @kabuto178 I think so, it is a little bit different. It you tab through a webpage buttons will also get focus, but then again, so do links. Like I said I have not tried it myself, but I think they can.

Comment: @kabuto178 Oops I forgot to answer your second question at first, it is there now.

Comment: just tested the button focus, it does change the focus but the cursor still blinks in the DIV

Comment: @kabuto178 Okay, it will need to be an input that moves the cursor then. Just a second and I will update my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24543/discussion-between-stephen-and-kabuto178)

Answer (score 3):

You could try to make the div uneditable on submit/before ajax request and enable editing once it's/ajax request is over. This needs to be done irrespective of weather it solves your problem coz it's a good practice to do so.

Comment: To question your point above, would it be better to make the div editable upon clicking it also?

Comment: as per my answer it's not needed once ajax completes it's already editable so click automatically works